# A reactjs module for incrementing the count on the press of a button -

Tags: javascript, reactjs

a react component that will display the current value of our counter.

The counter should start at 0.
There should be a button to add 1.
There should also be a button to subtract 1.

I am unable to understand the problem, as to what is it that I have missed or some wrong syntax.

```
const React = require('react');

class Counter extends React.Component{
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);

    this.state = { counter: 0 };
}

// Your event handlers 

  cincrement = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });
  };

  cdecrement = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter-1 });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.cincrement}>
            Decrement
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.cdecrement}>
            Increment
          </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The error that I get on running the code

> /runner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> SyntaxError: /home/codewarrior/index.js: Unexpected token (16:13)   14
>   | // Your event handlers    15 |
>
> > 16 |   cincrement = () => {
> >          |              ^   17 |     this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });   18 |   };   19 |
> >         at Parser.pp$5.raise (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
> >         at Parser.pp.unexpected (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseClassProperty (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2571:50)
> >         at Parser.parseClassProperty (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6157:20)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseClassBody (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2516:34)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseClass (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2406:8)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1843:19)
> >         at Parser.parseStatement (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5910:22)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2268:21)
> >         at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/runner/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2247:8)

Comment: the issue is that I am running this code on codewars not on my machine so there is no package.json

Comment: @AndrewL Is there any issue with the code above?  
That is my only concern as of now.

Comment: You cannot use arrow class functions in your environment. Change `cincrement = () => {` to `cincrement() {` and bind `this` to them.

Comment: Your code is relying on syntax that isn't standard JavaScript: 1. JSX, 2. Class Fields. Are you sure CodeWars is set up to handle **both** JSX and class fields? (It's standard for React projects to also transpile class fields, but...)

Comment: Unless codewars allows class fields this code won't work.

Comment: Side note: This is incorrect: `this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });` Instead: `this.setState(({counter}) => ({counter: counter + 1}));` Why: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your babel config does not include [class properties syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

You could use normal prototype methods and then prebind them in constructor

Also since your next state depends on the prev state you should pass a callback to `setState`

```
const React = require('react');

class Counter extends React.Component{
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);

    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.cincrement = this.cincrement.bind(this);
    this.cdecrement= this.cdecrement.bind(this)
}

// Your event handlers 

  cincrement(){
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter+1 }));
  }

  cdecrement() {
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter-1 }));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.cincrement}>
            Decrement
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.cdecrement}>
            Increment
          </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I beleive your response to be correct, the config does not support Class Fields

I tried your solution but got another error stating 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

So it might be issue and thanks for bringing to notice the binding

Comment: @SID The error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" is coming from somewhere else. This component does not access props anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

React needs [binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) on event handlers.

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

One way to avoid this is to define the handlers inside the constructor:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = ev => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Your original code, IIRC, needs a special [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.html) to work.